# How to get date from a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have 2 timestamps with different format:

```
1/2/2021 21:15
19-3-2021 21:15
```

Is there a method in javascript to get just the date for these timestamps?

Expected output:

```
'1/2/2021'
'19/3/2021'
```

I know using `substr()` is not effective as the length of the date string can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [**split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert string into array based on space.
2. Then use [**replaceAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) on each element of the array, which will replace all the dash(-) which are in dates to slash (/)
3. [**Use includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if slash(/) is present or not, as it will separate data(d/m/y) with time(h:m)

```js
function getDateFun(timestamp) {
  let timeStr = timestamp;

  let splitStamp = timeStr.split(" ");
  let dates = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < splitStamp.length; i++) {
    if (splitStamp[i].includes("/") ||        splitStamp[i].includes("-"))
      dates.push(splitStamp[i]);
  }
  console.log(dates.toString());
}

getDateFun("1/2/2021 21:15");
getDateFun("19-3-2021 21:15");
getDateFun("1/2/2021 21:15 19-3-2021 21:15");
```

## Update

Based on [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) comment, the same can be achieved by using [**Regular Expressions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [**replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
function getDateFun(timestamp){
return timestamp.split(' ')[0]
                .replace(/\D/g, '/');
}

console.log(getDateFun("28/03/2021 07:50"));
console.log(getDateFun("19-02-2021 15:30"));
```

```js
function getDateFun(timestamp){
return timestamp
       .replace(/(\d+)\D(\d+)\D(\d+).*/,'$1/$2/$3')
}

console.log(getDateFun("28/03/2021 07:50"));
console.log(getDateFun("19-02-2021 15:30"));
```

Comment: Or `timestamp.split(' ')[0].replace(/\D/g, '/')` or `timestamp.replace(/(\d+)\D(\d+)\D(\d+).*/,'$1/$2/$3')`. :-)

Comment: @RobG Thank you for your valuable comment, I have updated my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the two timestamp formats are the only ones to which you need to cater, we can try:

```js
function getDate(input) {
    return input.replace(/\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$/, "")
                .replace(/-/g, "/");
}

console.log(getDate("1/2/2021 21:15"));
console.log(getDate("19-3-2021 21:15"));
```

The first regex replacement strips off the trailing time component, and the second replacement replaces dash with forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dates have a space character between the date and time you can use the `split()` method:

```js
let firstDate = '1/2/2021 21:15';
let secondDate = '19-3-2021 21:15';

// [0] is the first element of the splitted string
console.log(firstDate.split(" ")[0]); 
console.log(secondDate.split(" ")[0]);
```

Or you can then also use `substr()` by first finding the position of the space character:

```js
let firstDate = '1/2/2021 21:15';
let secondDate = '19-3-2021 21:15';

let index1 = firstDate.indexOf(' ');
let index2 = secondDate.indexOf(' ');

console.log(firstDate.substr(0, index1)); 
console.log(secondDate.substr(0, index2));
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted may I ask? Because my dates are separated by space

Comment: @BreadBoard.ini Not only did I get one downvote, I got two!

Comment: @Ivan86 I don't understand how can someone downvote a Question or an Answer without pointing out the mistake.  Mine as well as Tim Biegeleisen are also downvoted.

Comment: @NotABot I've seen them discuss this in meta. They were proposing that you shouldn't be able to downvote without leaving an explanation. But I don't know if it will ever be implemented.

Comment: @NotABot That means you also got an upvote, since it's showing 0... I got an upvote too, possibly from the OP. But I got 2 downvotes as well.

Comment: @Ivan86 You also got one upvote as it is showing only 1 down vote.

Comment: @NotABot All together I got 6 points :)  10 - 4

Comment: @BreadBoard.ini btw just out of curiosity, were you the upvoter?

Comment: @Ivan86 Your, mine, as well as Tim's answers, are working according to the question asked. Still don't understand who upvoted and who downvote..   Let me upvote yours and  tim's answer as they are working fine.

Comment: @NotABot I was just about to propose the same. Upvoting all on page including OP question.

Comment: @Ivan86 Yep I upvoted everyone's since its all working